# How to implement cookie in profile picture uploading?

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a problem figuring this out. How to implement **cookie** in processing uploaded picture name ?

I have 2 files :

**index.php** (where you can set your profile picture).

```
 <form action="setPicture.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

**setPicture.php**

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

If a user upload's a profile picture it will be saved in *data/img/admin* , i must use that source to save it inside the **cookie** and then get redirected to the main page **index.php** with the profile picture is set .

Can someone helps me to understand the implementation ?

Here is the complete code of my work.
https://jsfiddle.net/u5c4sz6u/1/

Comment: First of all why you are saving source in cookie ? you can use session for that

Comment: In your code you have not uploaded the file. Where is the file uploading code in that ?

Comment: i have no ideea how to use the cookie ,thats why im asking some help :),and if i try to upload a picture it will upload it in data/img/admin 
PS: i went over the cookie tutorials but my head cant understand it

Comment: @AlankarMore you are right is not uploading , must have changed the code my mistake . It uploaded earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cookie* is usually used to *record* mini temporary data that you want to access later when some interactions occur (ex: pages interaction). In your case, you want to save the cookie's value as the *path* of the *successfully* uploaded image.

In simple case you could just :

- If the image has been uploaded *succesfully*, take the path of the file and then save it to a cookie :

  ```
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

     $full_path =$target_dir.( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    // set the cookie
   setcookie("mypathvalueissaved",$full_path, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */ 
   }
  ```

now a new cookie created with a name of *`"mypathvalueissaved"`* and its value is *`$full_path`* which is the the value of the *target path* + *file's name* (contains extension).

- Later on when you want to access the cookie just refer to the *cookie's name* (even in the different pages, it will be recognized since *$_COOKIE* is a superglobal array with assumption that you don't set the cookie for a specific domain ) with `$_COOKIE["mypathvalueissaved"]`.
  Like when the uploading is successfully, set the cookie then do redirecting and finally set the value of the cookie as the value of a `<img src= >`, like `<img src="<?php echo $_COOKIE['mypathvalueissaved'];?>">`.

  ```
   // if the cookie with a "mypathvalueissaved" name was successfully created before
   if (isset($_COOKIE["mypathvalueissaved"])){ 

     }
  ```

This is just a *brief* explanation, you can improve & expand its usage by yourself.

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted ,thank you , by the way if i want the default.png img ,should i write it inside src ? 
i did it like this before i wrote ur code 
`<a><img src="data/img/admin/default.png"></a>` , anyway i will study your code and read more to understand . Thanks again :)

Comment: To be honest it isn't quite suitable to implement image's path saving in a cookie :) , usually it's saved in db or (barely) *.txt*. Because think it like this, the cookie will always be checked in *index.php* either *before* (user hasn't uploaded the image yet) or *after* the redirection (user has uploaded the image), so for example when the cookie expires after an hour, the user will be forced to upload the image again since the information on the previous cookie had been destroyed, but If it's just a *temporary* operation then that won't be matter. Anyway you're welcome! :)